# Клик на textblock wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как сделать `TextBlock` кликабельним.
Нужно соблюдать mvvm концепт, в вюшке бинд на метод или команду в `ViewModel`

```
public ICommand RememberMeCommand
{
    get
    {
        rememberMeChecked = !_rememberMe;
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        rememberMeChecked = !_rememberMe;
    }
}
```

Прописываю бинд сюда, но оно даже не заходит при нажатии, нету захода на точку дебагера. Как реализовать?

Comment: Приведите код текстом, а не картинкой. Почему вы считаете, что `get { return null; }` должно работать нормально?

Comment: не считаю что должно работать проблема в том что тупо не заходить при нажатии дебагер в команду 
тупо не видит ее сколько не жми на тексблок

Comment: Забейте на текстблок и привяжите команду к обычной кнопке, как заставите работать ее — замените кнопку на текстблок так как у меня в ответе. Всё остальное — не по сути вопроса. На суть вопроса я вам ответил.

Comment: есть у меня второй вариант у меня етот текстблок должен бить как контент чек бокса 
но если его засунуть как контент то чекбокс сам постоянно размещается по центру перекривая собой текст 
і не в какую не хочет ставать слева

Comment: Как это относится к текущему вопросу? Если у вас есть другой вопрос — задайте его отдельно.

Comment: У вас неверно реализована ICommand. Логика команды должна быть не в get/set, а в Action RelayCommand!

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ClickCommand}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <TextBlock Text="Some text"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Или так:

```
<TextBlock Text="Some text">
    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Уже пробовал, даже через trigger  ничего не происходит 
По дебагеру даже не заходить в команду

Comment: Я лично только что проверил оба решения, они оба рабочие. Вы что-то делаете не так, возможно свойство для привязки не находится. Проверяйте ошибки биндинга.

Comment: обновил вопрос, первий раз работаю с wpf гдето лажаю похоже