# MVVM реализация событий контролов

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Всем доброго времени суток!
Пытаюсь разобраться с реализацией паттерна MVVM с использованием библиотек от GalaSoft. Застопорился на `EventToCommand`. Как я прочитал в [этой теме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868589/mvvm-light-adding-eventtocommand-in-xaml-without-blend-easier-way-or-snippet) данная конструкция используется для реализации обработчиков различных событий контролов через команды. Для проверки написал команду, которая выводит сообщение на экран:

```
public ICommand SelectGroup
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand<Object>(ExecuteSelectTagGroupCommand);
            }
        }
public void ExecuteSelectTagGroupCommand(object parameter)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("fdfd");
        }
```

Вызов данной команды я сделал для события `MouseDown` текстбокса и для события `Closing` окна приложения.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectGroup}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>



 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectGroup}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </TextBlock>
```

Однако работает только команда для окна. Причем если подписаться на событие `MouseDown` для текстбокса, то все работает нормально. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Используйте `MouseBinding`, это боле правильное решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/888200/218063

Comment: Интересный момент. `TextBlock` у меня используется в `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. И вот там команды, даже с использованием `MouseBinding`, не работают. Но если я вынесу его в отделный самостоятельный элемент - команды отрабатывают. Можно это исправить?

Comment: Приведите минимальный самодостаточный пример для воспроизведения. Может у вас там ошибки привязки или еще что... Должно всё работать и в шаблонах: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735522/218063

Comment: Проблема в том, что в приложении используются библиотеки DevExpress и привести все ровно в том же виде не получится. А насчет ошибок привязки, то это крайне маловероятно, потому что данные выводятся корректно, не срабатывает клик мыши по ним. Но точно такой же клик по отдельному текстбоксу работает как надо.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, собственно данная вещь не работает и с обычным TreeView. Вот ссылка на мою "проблему" https://dropmefiles.com/WTH4z .

Comment: Ну, как я и говорил у вас проблема с привязкой: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvbkd.png Дело в том, что `{Binding SelectGroup}` это привязка к экземпляру `Device`, а не к корневой VM. Как вы понимаете, в `Device` нет свойства `SelectGroup`

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `RelativeSource FindAncestor`

Comment: В вашем изначальном коде с `EventToCommand` абсолютно та же проблема, ну и в том топике, на который я вам дал ссылку можно посмотреть как вам добраться до команды: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735522/218063

Comment: именно в этом и была ошибка! Спасибо!